# EMERGENT A* search maze C++

Tags: c++, search, maze

The question is to write a A* search code to escape the maze given with C++ code.

I have the code being able to compile but fail to execute. When I run it in terminal, an error "segmentation fault (core dumped)" occurred. Can anyone help me out out this problem? Thanks.

The code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>  
#include <cmath> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double heu(int a, int b)
{    return sqrt((a-11)*(a-11) + (b-0)*(b-0));}


class step{
  public:
  int x, y;
  string path;
  int pathcost() const {return path.length() - 1;}
  double totalcost() const {return ((double) pathcost() + heu(x,y));}
  bool comp(const step & , const step & )  ;
  };

bool comp( const step & a, const step & b) {return (a.totalcost() < b.totalcost());}

void explore(step currentstep, char Maze[][12],vector<step> allsteps){ 

   step tempstep;
 if (( currentstep.x != 0 ) && (Maze[currentstep.x -1][currentstep.y] != '1'))
   {tempstep.x = currentstep.x -1; tempstep.y = currentstep.y;
   tempstep.path = currentstep.path + 'W';
   allsteps.push_back(tempstep); }

if (( currentstep.x != 11 ) && (Maze[currentstep.x +1][currentstep.y] != '1'))

  { tempstep.x = currentstep.x +1; tempstep.y = currentstep.y;
   tempstep.path = currentstep.path + 'E';
   allsteps.push_back (tempstep);}

if (( currentstep.y != 0 ) && (Maze[currentstep.x][currentstep.y -1] != '1'))
 {tempstep.x = currentstep.x; tempstep.y = currentstep.y -1;
   tempstep.path = currentstep.path + 'N';
   allsteps.push_back (tempstep);
  }

if (( currentstep.y != 11 ) && (Maze[currentstep.x][currentstep.y +1] != '1'))
  {tempstep.x = currentstep.x; tempstep.y = currentstep.y +1;
   tempstep.path = currentstep.path + 'S';
   allsteps.push_back (tempstep);}
}


int main()
{
string txt =     "000100000000000100111111100100000000000000000000011001001101001001001000001000001000001000001000001111101011100000001000000111101000000100000000";


char Maze[12][12];
for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
for( int j =0; j<12;j++){
     int k=i*12+j;
     Maze[j][i]=txt[k];
     }}

vector<step> allsteps;
step currentstep;
currentstep.x=0;currentstep.y=11;
currentstep.path="";
vector<step>::iterator itr;

while ((currentstep.x != 11) && (currentstep.y!=0)){
  explore(currentstep, Maze,allsteps);
  sort(allsteps.begin(), allsteps.end(),comp);
  itr=allsteps.begin();
  currentstep = *itr;}
  cout<<currentstep.path;
 system ("PAUSE");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiling your code with gcc I get the following segfault information:

```
#0  0x00000000004016e2 in step::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdb60) at main.cpp:13
#1  0x0000000000401468 in main () at main.cpp:73
```

If I go to those lines:

```
currentstep = *itr;}
```

And

```
class step{
```

Maybe it helps you to find something.

Check the content of the vector, and print the current iteration.

Just a note

```
void explore(step currentstep, char Maze[][12],vector<step> allsteps)
```

should be

```
void explore(step currentstep, char Maze[][12],vector<step>& allsteps)
```

Edit:The problem is you specify the parameter as value instead of reference, when you access the first element at

```
 itr=allsteps.begin();
```

allsteps is empty, so `*itr` will be an invalid iterator and will segfault your code.

Comment: I have tried to amend it and it does run now but it looks like keep on loading and not result

Comment: I think the itr problem is not valid because after one execution of explore() function the allstep vector is no longer empty

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting break points and debugging the code?

```
 cout << "this is a test line, it will print if my program gets past this point." << endl;
 cin.get();
```

Comment: I am using Dev - C++ and i think i cant use this method :(

Comment: You can always output text instead of using a break point and if you really want to work your way through it you can do a cin in order to make the program wait for you

Comment: it is not able to execute after using cin

Comment: maybe where Raistmaj's answer suggests.  basically anywhere where the error could be coming up, and if you see one break point, but not the next one, you know the error was somewhere in between them

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to pass allsteps by reference not by value:

```
void explore(step currentstep, char Maze[][12],vector<step>& allsteps){
```

not

```
void explore(step currentstep, char Maze[][12],vector<step> allsteps){
```